# Reading and writing on webcam stream

Tags: java, stream, jmf, augmented-reality

Is it possible to use java to write into a webcam stream? I've tried JMF and got it to capture the image but couldn't find a possibility to write into the stream.

Comment: Write into a webcam stream? I have hard time in imaging where the stream should finally end up. Does the webcam have a builtin monitor or so, so that one can see movies on it?

Comment: It's not that. I would see it as a global change of the webcam image so that applications which use the image get a preprocessed version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard about the possibility of writing webcam stream in Java.

As I know, there are few technologies which can do this work:

1) Based on Adobe technologies: webcam -> Adobe FME -> Adobe FMS -> Flash / Flex app
2) OpenSource variant: webcam -> Flash app -> Red 5 Server -> Flash (Client)
3) microsoft also has technologies to work with webcam

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://www.openimaj.org/

you need maven and subversion to use this library. pretty handy in image processing and stream controlling